# debug a shared library in Linux

Tags: linux, debugging, shared

so, we have a plugin for Softimage. Unfortunately, the Linux version has a bug somewhere.

Is there a nice way to debug that plugin, a shared library, while it's used by Softimage? Is it possible to use Eclipse, or any other IDE, to debug the plugin?

We really need this done as fast as possible. The bug itself looks very simple, but we just don't know where to look.

Comment: What's wrong with running your program under `gdb`?

Comment: It's how to do it that we want to know! Is it possible even if we don't have access to the source of the program ? Do you have a link to suggest that we can actually do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a nice way to debug that plugin, a shared library, while it's used by Softimage?

Yes.

> Is it possible to use Eclipse, or any other IDE, to debug the plugin?

Yes.

You use any debugger in exactly the same way you use it to debug any other executable:

```
gdb /path/to/exe
(gdb) run <arguments>
```

> Is it possible even if we don't have access to the source of the program

Why do you think you need that source?

Presumably the bug manifests itself as a crash, error, or some other incorrect behavior. Run the program until crash point, then use `where` command to find out where you crashed, `print` to examine variables, etc. etc.

If there is not enough information at the crash point to diagnose the problem, set breakpoints and re-run as appropriate.

Comment: I know I'm annoying about this, but is it possible to do that in Eclipse with the visual interface ?

Comment: @widgg Yes: in *exactly* the same way you would debug any other executable.